# Pulling specific version of Tensorflow from dockerhub

Tags: docker, tensorflow, version, dockerhub

I am trying to pull a base image of TensorFlow from docker hub and can only understand the docs of pulling the latest image

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

I would like to have TensorFlow 1.3.0 in my docker image instead of 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.3.0
```

You can get all version TAG from
[Tensorflow DockerHub Repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=26&ordering=last_updated)